# editableCellDidEndOnExit executes too late

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, uitableview

I have a detail controller set up for editing tableviewcells. When I finish editing a cell, I use editableCellDidEndOnExit to queue a corresponding change to my data base. This works fine when the focus goes from one cell to another. However, when the user presses the Save button in my nav bar,  focus goes from the cell being edited to the Save button. As a consequence, the action called by pressing the Save button gets executed first and then the editableCellDidEndOnExit action is executed.

The problem with this is that I commit the queued changed (using NSManagedObject:save:) to the database when the save button is pressed. It is only after that when editableCellDidEndOnExit is called and the change to the last cell is queued. It doesn't get committed (saved).

What can I do to assure that the last cell edit is made before the save?

I suppose I can store a pointer to the cell that is being edited using editableCellDidBeginEditing, and then refer to that value when the save button is pressed. Can someone offer other ideas?

Here is some of the relevant code:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Client Info";
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave target:self action:@selector(doneSave)] autorelease];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(cancel)] autorelease];
        keyboardShown = NO;
        currentCell = nil;

        dataInterface = [DataInterfaceObject alloc]; // a singleton
        clientMO = [[Client alloc] init ];
    }
    return self;
}


// queue the change
- (void)editableCellDidEndEditing:(EditableCell *)cell {
    [clientMO setValue:cell.textField.text forKey:cell.keyName];  
};


// commit (save) the changes
- (void) doneSave {
    [dataInterface commitChangesAndNotify:@"clientUpdate"];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and

```
-(void) commitChangesAndNotify:(NSString *)notification{
    if([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges])
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:notification object:nil];  // tell everybody that needs to know about this change (so they can update their view data sources)
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
    }     
}
```

Comment: I think your pointer idea would work fine. It's probably normal to have to prepare several ways of processing user actions, depending on how the user navigates. At least, in my limited experience, I've found it necessary to do quite a lot of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried several things to work this out, but in every case, the event for **editableCellDidEndEditing:cell:** always would be handled after the changes were committed. I tried changing the order of my code to see if I could get the event to be handled sooner. I tried replacing the method **doneSave** with two methods, where the first method, **willSaveOnExit**, queues an event to call the second method, **didSaveOnExit**. The idea was to put the commit operation into **didSaveOnExit** and have the event queued after the **editableCellDidEndEditing**.

Unfortunately, I discovered that the event calling **editableCellDidEndEditing:cell** was never generated until the view controller was popped and the previous view had appeared. So trying to rearrange the event queue was pointless. I lost patience trying to figure out a way around that, because I couldn't think of a way to communicate to the detailed view controller that the previous view had appeared. (I could probably figure it out, but, at the time, I wasn't feeling too creative in that direction.)

None of the above was necessary, after all.

### ***Here is what I ended up doing:***

(which is very much like what I suggested in my question)

I created an ivar in the tableviewcontroller called currentCell, which I set in the method **editableCellDidBeginEditing:cell:** pointing to the cell where editing is being done.

currentCell is initialized to nil in **viewDidAppear**

I changed this code (see my question for the original), wrapping the code in the conditional

```
- (void)editableCellDidEndEditing:(EditableCell *)cell {
    if (currentCell){
        [clientMO setValue:currentCell.textField.text forKey:currentCell.keyName]; // update the value 
    }
}
```

I changed the Save button handler method to this

```
- (void) doneSave {
    [self editableCellDidEndEditing:currentCell];
    currentCell = nil;
    [dataInterface commitChangesAndNotify:@"clientUpdate"];    
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

(adding the first two lines to the version in my question)

Now, I know that if the save button has been pressed, then the user is done editing, so I want to call **editableCellDidEndEditing:cell:** one last time *before I commit the changes*. But since my code is calling (rather than the event handler) I have to provide the cell pointer, which I obtained when the cell edit began, and had put in currentCell.

I then set currentCell to nil, indicating that there is no longer a current cell. Now, remember that I said there is still going to be an event queued up for **editableCellDidEndEditing:cell:** by the time the previous view appears. When that method executes, the conditional test for currentCell (!=nil) drops through, and the code is bypassed.

So in the end, it appears that everything is working in the right order, even though the superfluous call to **editableCellDidEndEditing:cell:** still is occurring.

I'm happy for now.